# How to implement Polymorphic objects in CouchDB / NoSQL?

Tags: nosql, couchdb, polymorphism

I'd like to implement Polymorphic objects in a NoSQL / Document DB?
What is best practice?

Example: 
Master Class
**Item Object** (All should have Item.Title, Item.Subtitle, Item.IconURL)

**SubClasses: ItemPhoto, ItemPDF, ItemURL, ItemHTML**
(Each subclass would have different properties)

I'd like to list all Items Generically - then get specific data when i drill down.

**Possible Options:**

Save a two different Documents -with Master/Child Type & ID
Save all as SubClass Documents with Internal Item Object

Other options??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

CouchDB stores documents (data), not classes (data with code). There's the code in map, validation, list, and show functions which handle documents, but those documents are plain objects that carry data only.

In your example, you can define a library function to check that a given document contains the data of an item, and then use this function to decide what to do. For example:

```
// in a "appTypes" library:
exports.isItem = function(doc) {
  return doc.Title && doc.Subtitle && doc.IconURL;
}

// in a map function
function(doc) {
  var appTypes = require('appTypes');
  if (appTypes.isItem(doc)) {
    // doc is an Item...
  }
}
```

Obviously you can put all code belonging to an Item in an Item class and create instances of that class initialized with the data in the doc. But that's your choice, and does not change how CouchDB will handle the document.